# Creating knock out tournament matches in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating knocked tournament matches for soccer games.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Team1']   = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
df['Score1']  = [1,2,3,1,2,4]
df['Team2']   = ['U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
df['Score2']  = [2,1,2,2,3,3]
df['Match']   = df['Team1']  + ' Vs '+ df['Team2']
df['Match_no']= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
winner = df.Score1>df.Score2
df['winner']  = np.where(winner,df['Team1'],df['Team2'])
df ['Stage']  ='R16
```

Let's say, the above code is for  knocked out stage. By running above code, we have a winner for each match ( 6 winners). Each match is numbered as 1,2,3 and so on.

What I want to do is to create another date frame for next stage of tournament.
In next stage , we will have 3 matches.
In these matches, winner from odd match number and even match number will play (i.e. U vs B,C vs X, Y vs F)
I just need teams to be in new dataframe.
Can anyone advise me how to extract those teams?

Thanks

Zep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try,

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df1['Team1']=df.loc[0::2,'winner'].values
df1['Team2']=df.loc[1::2,'winner'].values
```

Comment: Hi @pyd,if I want to set up  the team by groupby, how can i apply it?

Comment: By what condition? Can you create a new question with your df and expected df

Comment: Hi pyd,
Below is the link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51095006/using-groupby-and-loc-to-set-up-a-new-dataframe

Answer (score 1):

You can use the list slicing, `some_list[start:stop:step]`

```
winners_list = df['winner'].tolist()
df1 =  pd.DataFrame()
df1['Team1'] = winners_list[0::2]
df1['Team2'] = winners_list[1::2]
```

- Take the winners from `df` as list (you can also take as `pandas.core.series.Series` and use slicing but when you use it to create a data frame you will face issues because of indexing)
- Create a new dataframe and take the even indexed elements from winners list as Team1
- Take the odd indexed elements from the winners list as Team2.

Comment: Thanks Dinesh. I really appreciate your advice.