# Using groupby and loc to set up a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-loc

I have a DataFrame as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Team1']   = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','A','B','C','D','E','F']
df['Score1']  = [1,2,3,1,2,4,1,2,3,1,2,4]
df['Team2']   = ['U','V','W','X','Y','Z','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
df['Score2']  = [2,1,2,2,3,3,2,1,2,2,3,3]
df['Match']   = df['Team1']  + ' Vs '+ df['Team2']
df['Match_no']= [1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6]
df['model']  = ['ELO','ELO','ELO','ELO','ELO','ELO','xG','xG','xG','xG','xG','xG']
winner = df.Score1>df.Score2
df['winner']  = np.where(winner,df['Team1'],df['Team2'])
```

What I want to do is to create another date frame for next stage of tournament. In next stage , we will have 3 matches for each Model (ELO and xG).I would like to groupby **Model**. These matches are groupped by **Model**, winner from match number 1 and  match number 1,winner from  Match number 3 vs match number 4 etc. will play (i.e. U vs B,C vs X, Y vs F). Then Can anyone advise me how to extract those teams?

my expected new dataframe will be as follow:

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame()
df1['Team1']   = ['U','C','Y','U','C','Y']
df1['Team2']   = ['B','X','F','B','X','F']

df1['Match']   = df1['Team1']  + ' Vs '+ df1['Team2']
df1['Match_no']= [1,2,3,1,2,3]
df1['model']  = ['ELO','ELO','ELO','xG','xG','xG']
```

How can I set up this?

Comment: I dont understand. Why is necessary groupby? [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51080193/2901002) should working if need pair odd and even rows. It should failed only if some group have unpair number of rows (is it possible?). Or need filter first 6 rows for each group first by `df.groupby('model').head(6)` ?

Comment: Dear Jez, Thanks for the reply.
I need to reuse the label from model in new dataframe. as I mentioned the new dataframe will have the following columns  Team1,Team2,Model.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for count per groups:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Team1'] = df.loc[::2, 'winner'].values
df1['Team2'] = df.loc[1::2, 'winner'].values
df1['Match'] = df1['Team1']  + ' Vs '+ df1['Team2']
model = df.loc[::2, 'model'].values
df1['Match_no'] = df1.groupby(model).cumcount() + 1
df1['model'] = model
print (df1)
  Team1 Team2   Match  Match_no model
0     U     B  U Vs B         1   ELO
1     C     X  C Vs X         2   ELO
2     Y     F  Y Vs F         3   ELO
3     U     B  U Vs B         1    xG
4     C     X  C Vs X         2    xG
5     Y     F  Y Vs F         3    xG
```

Comment: Yes Jez. It works. 
Thanks for the help. Now if I want to assign the match number for each match, Can i use cumcount based on Model?
i will give a try

Comment: @Zephyr - Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: Hi Jez, How about if I want to match 1 vs 3, 2 vs 4?

Comment: @Zephyr - Not sure if understand, my solution match 1 vs 3, 2 vs 4. Can you explain more?

Comment: Hi Jez, in my first dataframe (df), there were 6matches. Winner from each match will meet in next stage(I.e. winner from match 1 and winner from match 2). Now if I want to set up the match for next stage(I.e. winner from match 1 and winner from match 3, winner from match 2 and winner from match 4etc)

Comment: @Zephyr - I am lost, what is expected output for your another DataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you an answer although I have a hard time to understand what you mean by "winner from odd match number and even match number will play".

If this means that the winners from matches 1 and 2 pair, then 3 and 4 etc. you can do something as simple as

```
df1['Team1'] = df.loc[::2, 'winner']
df1['Team2'] = df.loc[1::2, 'winner']
```

given that your data is sorted as presented. You may achieve this by

```
df[df['model'] == 'ELO'].sort_values('Match_no')
```

etc. pandas-groupby seems not to be needed if I got you right.

Comment: Thanks Kay,
What i need for new data frame(df) is  list of winners from previous data frame (df). Then those team will be set up as matches (i.e. Winner Match 1 vs Winner match 2, and so on). Then I would like to use model from old data frame (df) to add as new column in new data frame (df1)